# Django sweetify

Tags: django, sweetalert, sweetalert2

I already read the documentation about https://github.com/Atrox/sweetify-django but I don't understand clearly, I already download and import requirement of sweetify in Django. I just want that if the record is updated the popup message **(sweetify)** will appear.

```
def studentrecords(request):
   if request.method == 'POST':
      id = request.POST.get("id")
      update = StudentsEnrollmentRecord.objects.get(id=id)
      update.Section = s
      update.save()
      sweetify.success(request, 'You did it', text='Your Form has been Updated',persistent='Hell yeah')
      return render(request, 'Homepage/selectrecord.html')
```

this is my html

```
{% load sweetify %}
{% sweetify %}
 <form  method="post" action="/studentrecords/" enctype="multipart/form-data">{% csrf_token %}
<table>
    {% for student in myrecord %}
    <tr>
        <td>Control #</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="id" value="{{student.id}}"></td>
        <td><input type="submit"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Name: </td>
        <td><input type="text" value="{{student.Student_Users.Firstname}} {{student.Student_Users.Lastname}} {{student.Student_Users.Middle_Initial}}"></td>
        <td>Course/Track</td>
        <td><input type="text" value="{{student.Courses}}"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Education Level: </td>
        <td><input type="text" value="{{student.Education_Levels}}"></td>
        <td>Strand: </td>
        <td><input type="text" value="{{student.strands}}"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Section: </td>
        <td>
            <select name="section">
                <option value="{{student.Section.id}}">{{student.Section}}</option>
                {% for sections in section %}
                <option value="{{sections.id}}">{{sections.Description}}</option>
                {% endfor %}
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>Payment Type: </td>
        <td><input type="text" value="{{student.Payment_Type}}" class="myform"></td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>
 </form>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@9"></script>
<script>
    Swal.fire(
  'Good job!',
   'Data Updated!',
  'success'
)
</script>
```

my settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    #my apps
    ….
    'sweetify'
]
SWEETIFY_SWEETALERT_LIBRARY = 'sweetalert2'
```

I didn't receive any error , but no popup message appear  **(sweetify)**

Comment: The documentation is lacking and the app doesn't include the javascript files needed, so it is assumed that you include the SweetAlert javascript library in your template. You don't have it in your example. Did you include the necessary code in your base template?

Comment: I updated the question. I post the script inside my html

Answer (score 3):

I think it might just be that you just need to load the script over CDN at the top of the page. Looking at the library, it seems like the template tag `{% sweetify %}` just loads in something a bit like this:

```
<script>
    Swal.fire(...)
</script>
```

So if you haven't yet loaded the sweet alerts script, `Swal` will just be undefined. You'll be able to confirm if this is the problem by opening up your dev-tools, and in the console you'll see a message which is something like "undefined has no property fire" or something like that. I'm curious, does the  `Swal.fire` you have at the bottom of the page work?

Answer (score 0):

First off, if you'd like to get a notification on any record update, I'd suggest using Signals rather than detecting the request method. It's a way more central and robust solution. Just add this to your `models.py`:

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save

@receiver(models.signals.post_save, sender=StudentsEnrollmentRecord)
def update_enrollment_record_handler(sender, updated_instance, **kwargs):
    """This method is called after every call of StudentsEnrollmentRecord.save"""
    sweetify.success(request, 'You did it', text='Your Form has been Updated',persistent='Hell yeah')
```

Second - POST is meant to create an object through a RestAPI, you should switch to UPDATE (includes all objects fields) or PUT (updates some of the objects fields).

Third - what happens when you add a print statement above the sweetify line? Does that print run? If not, then your whole setup doesn't even call the `studentrecords` method and you'll need to share more info so we can replicate the situation and/or advise further.

Comment: I would definitely recommend *against* doing this at the model level. The user notification is for a user to see, many model saves are not related to a user. In addition this taints the separation of concerns, since sweetalert is merely a frontend widget that doesn't need to be at the data level.

Comment: You say this: "I just want that if the record is updated the popup message (sweetify) will appear". Can you then rephrase the question? Are you not talking about the StudentsEnrollmentRecord model?

Comment: I am talking about the StudentsEnrollmentRecord model, but not in the admin site

Comment: Exactly, so if you want to do something on the model level, you should do it on the model level.

Comment: @JuraBrazdil Read in between the lines: "but not in the admin site". If you tie this to a post_save, then for one, you don't have a request object and for two, this will happen in the admin site, when you're updating through a data migration - everywhere, except bulk updates. Trust me, you don't want that.